# Changing a value in a Julia array and getting a strange result?

Tags: julia

I have the following code in Julia 1.4.2

```
temp = zeros(Int64, length(input_string))
i = 1

while i< length(input_string)
   temp[i] = input_string[i]
   i += 1
end
```

Using `input_string = "200"` I would expect this to return `temp = [2 0 0]`, but for some reason I return a 3 element Array{Int64,1} with values `[50, 48, 0].`

Is there a way for me to understand this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things to this:

1. Indexing a string (`input_string[i]`) gives you a character with type `Char`.
2. When updating the content of an array (`temp[i] = ...`) Julia converts the right hand side to the same element type as the array `temp`.
3. Converting a `Char` (right hand side) to an `Int` (which is the element type of `temp`) gives the ASCII value corresponding to the character.

The string `"200"` consists of the characters `'2'`, `'0'` and `'0'`, which ASCII values are `50`, `48` and `48` so we would expect `temp` to be `[50, 48, 48]` *BUT* the loop has a bug since it should check for `i <= length(input_string)`, so the last element beeing `0` is there from the initialization.

---

Here is the code I would have written for this:

```
function str_to_ints(str)
    r = Int[]
    for c in str
        ci = parse(Int, c)
        push!(r, ci)
    end
    return r
end
```

Example:

```
julia> str_to_ints("200")
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 0
 0
```

Answer (score 2):

When converting "200" to an `Int` vector [2, 0, 0] much shorter form is just:

```
parse.(Int,split("200",""))
```

or a 4x faster version

```
parse.(Int,(v for v in "200"))
```

and another 10% better:

```
parse.(Int,collect("200"))
```

Finally, the fastest I could think of:

```
[Int(v)-48 for v in "200"]
```